# How do I keep a messaging app in the foreground so that my status is always online even though I'm not using the app?

Tags: applications, xposed-framework

Let's say I'm using the messaging app and then switch over to another app, the messaging app will show that I'm not online, until I switch back to it bringing it to the foreground. I want my phone to always think that it is on the foreground so that I always show that I'm online. How can I achieve this?

Android 7 | Rooted

Comment: Not possible. You need to build a messaging app of your own (or hack the existing one) which runs a foreground service and fakes your online status.

Comment: What app can do that?

Comment: Sorry I'm not aware of. Normally the behavior you want doesn't make much sense. So I don't think any official messaging app/service would let you do that. That's why I said you need to build your own app provided that it's possible at all to integrate it with the backend messaging service.

Comment: What device model and manufacturer do you use? How the device handles apps in background is very different due to manufacturer implemented battery saving features. See also https://dontkillmyapp.com